# i cant make this pause menu work in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging

im trying to  [follow this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JivuXdrIHK0&ab_channel=Brackeys)

and i think i did everything right but its not doing anything then i click the escape button

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;

    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
        {
            if (GameIsPaused) 
            {
                Resume();
            }else 
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Resume() 
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }

    void Pause()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }

    public void LoadMenu()
    {
        Debug.Log("loading menu");
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("quiting game");
    }
}
```

[this is how the panel looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9X4j.png)

it was before in Canvas but i moved it because i was trying to make it work but it didnt help
someone knows maybe how to fix it?

Comment: UI components need to be children of a Canvas to be renderer. Child that panel to any Canvas object and it will show up again.

Comment: i placed the panel under the canvas but it didnt work

Comment: If you place it under the canvas from not being childed the scale can get messed up. Make sure on the Transform component that the position is 0,0,0 and the scale is 1,1,1. And are you sure that the reference of your script is assigned correctly in the inspector?

Comment: Which is the assigned reference? Because I can see your arrow pointing at an enabled parent object with only disabled children .... Are you maybe just enabling and disabling the wrong object?

Comment: hmm i think i massed up with the ui
i rewatched the video and i think i somehow fixed it, maybe i didnt place the panel?
[link](http://prntscr.com/11gntl0)
well now its working, thx